# Tomcat 9 with OpenJDK 11 doesn't recognize any Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy a Spring boot application on Tomcat 9.0.22 running OpenJDK 11 (11.0.2). I haven't built te .war file myself, so I can't change anything about that, but it should work.

I placed the .war file in the web-apps directory of the Tomcat 9 instance and started the service. Logging shows that everything starts up succesfully:

```
25-Jul-2019 17:27:24.041 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [D:\Applications\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\****.war]
25-Jul-2019 17:27:34.553 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
25-Jul-2019 17:27:34.600 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [D:\Applications\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\****.war] has finished in [10,559] ms
```

All default tomcat applications (/manager, /docs) work as expected, but when navigating to the page of the deployed .war file, it always returns 404. It also doesn't start the Java code, since no logging folder is created in the specified logging location for the application specifically.

I thought it might have something to do with the .war file, but just to make sure I threw it in a Tomcat 8 instance with JDK8. I knew the application would crash, but I this was visible in the logging of the tomcat instance as well as the application specific logging that was created.

I tried some other .war files, but it seems like none of them are executed correctly. It looks like it's just hosting them as some kind of http server and not executing any Java code. Is there some configuration thing I'm missing to startup the files? I'm using the default configuration of Tomcat.